# What is default git core.askpass configuration value?

Tags: git

I've set my `core.askpass` to an application and now I want to revert it back. How do I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove it:

```
git config --global --unset core.askpass
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the [default](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) is GIT_ASKPASS, followed by SSH_ASKPASS, followed by a simple password prompt. It's suggested you set it via the GIT_ASKPASS environment variable, though.